# Is it possible to calculate the regression sine function given three points?

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

Take the three points $(10,52)$, $(20,38)$ and $(50,-53)$

How would you calculate the sine regression line of the form: $$f(x)=A\ \sin{\frac{x+B}{C}}$$

In other words how would you calculate the constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ ?

Using the first two points I got as far as: $52\sin{\frac{20+B}{C}}=38\sin{\frac{10+B}{C}}$

I can't see what the best approach is.

All tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Better write the relation as

$$px+q=\arcsin(ry).$$

Then if you hypothesize some value of $r$, you get a system of $3$ equations in two unknowns, with the compatibility condition

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_0&1&\arcsin(ry_0)\\x_1&1&\arcsin(ry_1)\\x_2&1&\arcsin(ry_2)\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Hence you have reduced the problem to the search for the zeroes of a univariate function.

Beware anyway that $2k\pi+\arcsin(ry)$ and $(2k+1)\pi-\arcsin(ry)$ are also solutions...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot solve the system of equations with the inverse sine functions.

Comment: @Kantura: can't you compute a $3\times3$ determinant ?

Comment: Yes , but I get the expression $4\sin^{-1}(38r)-3\sin^{-1}(52r)-\sin^{-1}(-53r)=0$ which I don't know how to solve. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Kantura: maybe that wasn't clear, you can only address it numerically.

Comment: But the variable ''r'' is in the matrix right ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Kantura: do you know what it means to solve numerically ?

Comment: Not really , how do I do that ?

Comment: @Kantura: mh, this is a broad topic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: Daoust Ok , I'll have a read of that. But may I ask what the determinant of that matrix is ?

Comment: @Kantura: you showed it !

Comment: Ok good , at least I know that expression is right. I just need to learn how to add inverse sine functions with different coefficients.

Comment: @Kantura: I have not checked the coefficients and I will not. I don't think you still understand what is a numerical resolution.

Comment: Well I want to solve for ''r''. Then I can easily solve for ''p'' and ''q''.

Comment: @Kantura: why do you tell me, I know ?

Comment: Oh , because you questioned my understanding. I was clarifying what I am trying to do.